# React Formik Field onChange event handle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to handle onChange for Field component in React Formik, but it doesn't work. I also tried to handle it outside Formik component by:

```
handleChange(e) {
  console.log('changing');
}
<Field type="radio" name="players" value="1" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
```

but I am getting the warning:

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be
>   controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to
>   controlled (or vice versa).

For now my code looks like this:

```
<Formik
  onChange={() => {
    console.log('changing');
  }}
  onSubmit={(values) => {
    console.log('submitted');
  }}
>
{({ isSubmitting, handleChange }) => (
  <Form>
    <InputWrapper>
       <span>1</span>
       <Field type="radio" name="players" value="1" onChange={handleChange}/>
       <span>2</span>
       <Field type="radio" name="players" value="2" onChange={handleChange}/>
    </InputWrapper>
    <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
       {isSubmitting ? 'Loading..' : 'Start'}
    </button>
  </Form>
)}
</Formik>
```

Any tips/ideas?

Answer (score 20):

One issue I have found with introducing the onBlur:handleBlur to your Formik Field is that it overrides the Formik Validation.

Use `onKeyUp={handleChange}`

This solved said problem

Comment: what will be for select element

Comment: What about select elements, checkboxes, radio buttons, upload, etc...

Comment: for select one can use `onClick`

Comment: `onClick` works for checkboxes/radios

Comment: How can I get access to the initialValues on the formik with this onKeyUp?

Answer (score 11):

You must to use the InputProps of Field like the following...

```
import { TextField } from 'formik-material-ui';

<Field
  type="radio" 
  name="players" 
  value="2"
  component={TextField} 
  InputProps={{ onBlur:handleBlur }}/>
```

To use the InputProps in the Field you need to use a component TextField from the formik-material-ui lib.

Another way is use the onKeyUp or onKeyDown, that functions work ok with Field and that functions are like onChange

```
<Field 
  type="radio" 
  name="players" 
  value="2" 
  onKeyUp =this.handleChange/>
```

Comment: Another way is use the onKeyUp or onKeyDown, that functions work ok with Field and that functions are like onChange
<Field
  type="radio" 
  name="players" 
  value="2" 
  onKeyUp =this.handleChange/>

Comment: what will be for select ? onKeyUp is not working for select

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad are you using a mouse to click it :)  ...jokes aside, I'm also curious how to do this for a select. It seems `InputProps` are not available on a normal <Formik> <Field>

Answer (score 3):

I found one trick which worked well for me, you can use "values" of formik and call a method passing the "values" as parameter and perform the action using new values.

```
const handleUserChange = (userId: number) => {
    //userId is the new selected userId
  };


 <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        enableReinitialize
      >
        {({ isValid, isSubmitting, values }) => (
          <Form>
            <table className="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Users</td>
                  <td>
                    <Field name="userId" className="form-control" as="select">
                      <option value="">--select--</option>
                      {data.Users.map((user, index) => (
                        <option key={user.id} value={user.id}>{`User ${index + 1}`}</option>
                      ))}
                    </Field>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                {handleUserChange(values.userId)}
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-sm-12">
                <SubmitButton label="Save" submitting={isSubmitting} disabled={!isValid || isSubmitting} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
```

Answer (score 2):

One issue I had when I used the onKeyUp event was that it wouldn't work on input type of dates. So I used onInput Event instead.

```
    onInput={handleChange}
```

Works for input type of text and type of dates as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Grid item xs={12}>
       <Field
           type="email"
           name="email"
           as={FormField}
           label="Email *"
           validate={validate}
           value={emailId}
           onChange={e => {
               setFieldTouched('type');
               handleChange(e)
           }}
       />
       <MDBox>
           <MDTypography component="div" variant="caption" color="error" fontWeight="regular">
               {<div style={{
                   cursor: 'pointer', marginTop: styleMt
               }} onClick={emailStatus != 'ACTIVE' ? handleRestore : ''}>{errorMessages}</div>}
           </MDTypography>
       </MDBox>
   </Grid>
```

Comment: Hello, please add some details about your answer - what you changed, why you changed it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `onKeyUp={handleChange}`. This worked for me when I encountered a similar issue